# jquerymobile double up of initial page in DOM

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm having an issue whereby I navigate around my site but when I return to the first (initial) page of the website, the DOM doubles up. I.E there are two div data-role pages with the same ID.

It's because as you navigate around your site, for some reason, JQM always keeps the first initial page in the DOM, but then when you return to it, it doubles up (and consequently your handlers on elements don't work because they are inside the hidden data-role="page" element and the new ones have no handlers..

Have I done something wrong here or is this a common problem one needs to work around in JQM? Thanks

I also don't understand why JQM holds onto the initial page... I thoguht it was supposed to hold on to the last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this issue: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2258

The first page will never be removed

Answer (score 0):

So use

> a href='#id'  // jump to #id, which is already in DOM

but NOT

> a href='index.html#id'  // jump to 'create' a new one